# "sudo apt autoremove" command doesn't work ("/var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process")

Tags: apt, sudo, package-management, lock

I've tried solutions like editing on `panasoniclpd.init` file and it doesn't work
too. This problem keeps shown whenever I try to update or install from the CLI

```
sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for lahlohi: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for lahlohi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up unattended-upgrades (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.14) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you try rebooting yet?

Comment: Have you tried finding the process ID that locks the file from the error message and kill that process?

Comment: @Panki nope, but I'm working to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If rebooting is not an option and you have access to the machine, try the following:

1) Find the process ID that locks the file from the error message:

```
$ sudo lsof /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
frontend 44515 root 4uW REG 252,0 60012 55592027 /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

2) Check the process via `ps`:

```
$ sudo ps auxf | grep 44515
root 44515 0.0 0.0 60700 2196 pts/0 S+ Feb18 0:00 | _ /usr/bin/perl -w 
/usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.postinst configure 3.1.0-3ubuntu0.2
```

3) Kill the process.

```
$ sudo kill -9 44515
```

4) Try your `apt` command again.